# Paginación ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tengo un ASPxGridView que lo relleno con un DataTable y le he puesto una paginación de 10. Los datos los muestra bien pero al cambiar de página se queda en blanco. Si alguien sabe porque puede ser.

ASPxGridView:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvAsignaturasExcel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SettingsPager-PageSize="10">
    <Columns>
       <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Code" Caption="Códigofgdrgdfgdfgfgfg" VisibleIndex="0" 
       meta:resourcekey="GridViewDataTextColumnResource1" 
       ShowInCustomizationForm="True">
       </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

       <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" Caption="Nombre" VisibleIndex="1" 
       meta:resourcekey="GridViewDataTextColumnResource2" 
       ShowInCustomizationForm="True">
       </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

       <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Subjects" Caption="Agignaturas" VisibleIndex="2"
       meta:resourcekey="GridViewDataTextColumnResource3" 
       ShowInCustomizationForm="True">
       </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
    <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Datos:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Code",typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Subjects", typeof(string));


foreach (var item in list)
{
  table.Rows.Add(item.Codigo, item.Nombre,  item.Asignatura );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega el evento OnPageIndexChanging

```
gvAsignaturasExcel_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            gridview.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            //aquí llamas de nuevo el metodo que te carga el gridview
        }
```

saludos